# Most inspirational mathematical books

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

I would like to know which books on mathematics (from university texts to divulgative pop-math books) inspired you the most.

My choice is Spivak's Calculus, which is, IMHO one of the most inspirational mathematics books I've ever read: it has very meaningful examples and clear explanations.

Answer (score 3):

[The Princeton companion to mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691118809) is surely a tour de force. It is a joint effort of many leading mathematicians, and show the beauty of mathematics rigorously in an inspiring way.

Answer (score 2):

I'll second Spivak, but I was also inspired by E.T. Bell's Men of Mathematics, which has a lot of math content.  And not a book per se (though there are collections), Martin Gardner's columns in Scientific American were also inspiring.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, though it's not exactly a text for mathematicians, Quine's *Methods of Logic* basically kicked off my interest in mathematics. It's the text I taught myself formal logic from, and the text in which I started to appreciate the beauty of formal logic.

Probably second is Goldblatt's *Topoi*, which introduced me, in one fell swoop, to category theory, topos theory, a smattering of topological ideas, and most of my basic set theoretic concepts. Most of the math I learned subsequently was originally part of an effort to understand this book better.