# Math books for middle schoolers (Book Recommendation)

Tags: book-recommendation

(I suspect that there are other questions asking for math books accessible to middle school students but I couldn't find them. )

I am looking for math books for middle school students who find math taught in class easy. Assuming that they have knowledge of arithmetic (basic operations on numbers), some geometry and algebra what books could challenge them?

Arithmetic- Addition, subtraction, multiplication, division.
Geometry- What polygons are, practical geometry involving the Pythagoras theorem, finding areas with very little experience writing proofs.
Algebra- Solving linear equations in one variable.

I was thinking number theory, but I am not sure if there are books that are accessible to them and also interesting enough.

Comment: You could check out the Art of Problem Solving textbooks, but be aware that the problems are very challenging.

Comment: Can you tell your grade? Is it between 6-8?

Comment: @LoveInvariants Yes.

Comment: The O.P of that problem had already finished an undergraduate course and wanted to review all of math which I believe is very different from approaching math for the first time.

Comment: Perhaps helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/832223/what-was-the-book-that-opened-your-mind-to-the-beauty-of-mathematics/834956#834956

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend book named **Mathematical Circles** by Dmitri Fomin. It is read by most olympiad aspirants in my country especially the ones who are starting to prepare, 7-9 grade students.